# criteria / heuristics to decide between copying the entire table, joining for further queries or keep nesting the queries [postgres]

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I'll try to explain the very confusing title of this question.

I need to run a bunch of queries after pre-processing a large table (billions of rows, couple of dozen columns). Pre-processing involves bringing some data from other tables (left-join) and calculating groups for the data in the table (e.g. groups of rows with consecutive dates). So, in the end, the queries need to run on the original table and the added columns in the pre-processing.

I have been looking for criteria / heuristics to decide between the following approaches:

1. Copy the whole table with the pre-processing results into a new table (`CREATE TABLE final_table AS (preprocessing_query)`) so I can query directly the `final_table`.
2. Store in a new table only the new columns calculated in the pre-processing and then use a join with the original table for every query.
3. Do not store the results of the pre-processing at all and use subqueries, nestes queries, CTE or the like, to sort-of include the pre-processing into the final queries.

I usually tend to favor the first approach, just because it leads to cleaner code. All the pre-processing and the final queries are several small and easy to read and mantain queries. But of course copying all the data can be an expensive operation.

Option 2 entails a bit more convoluted queries, but you save on copying a lot of data, and incurr only the cost of joining that (which can be expensive as well, but it is a join agains a PK on the original table, so not that bad).

Option 3 can lead to proverbial long and complex queries. But you save on copying data and joining them.

So, I was looking for authoritative sources to deal with this this kind of problem in PostgreSQL, considering its nature (I mean, Postgres is not an OLAP-database optimized to operate on large portions of the data and it does not use a columnar format, and so on).

So far, it's been a bit of trial and error, in which I end up with something in between options 1 and 2.

Comment: I would measure the performance of different approaches and pick the fastest. There is no point trying to guess, you need to measure how fast your real life data is processed on your hardware. If there is no significant difference in performance, then other considerations come into play.

Comment: Largely depends on undisclosed details like your *"bunch of queries"* to run, exact table definitions and data distribution, indexes, server configuration, available resources, concurrency, Postgres version ... As is, your question leads nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my 10+ years of experience the choice largely depends on your resource constraints.

1. Will be IO and storage space heavy.
2. Will be code complex, but you can overcome this by using a view to combine the two tables and all other code uses the view.
3. Honestly, I can't imagine you are not overflowing into tempdb for this (with a billion records), so I don't see the benefit.

Ultimately, I would choose 2 for my environments, because the IO processing time to copy everything into a new table would be much slower than creating a new table with the primary key of the original table.